Visual Studio Code - use SQL formatter to format HQL files
I would like a good formatter for HQL files. I found one extension dedicated for Hive & Spark but I don't like the way it formats my queries. I prefer the way the SQL Formatter works. Is there a way to make the SQL Formatter work on .hql files?

One indirect solution option is to change the Language Mode to SQL, I'm not sure if this helps you 100%.
Use CTRL/CMD+SHIFT+P to open VSCode's command panel and look for Change Language Mode to change to SQL and then you can use your SQL Formatter Extension.

This works as a workaround - I have to choose the language mode for each HQL file but the SQL formatter works, thank you!
